# Google Sheets: ImportXML Returns Empty Value

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

First of all, I know there is another question about this, but I couldn't really understand how to apply it to my problem.
So I'm trying to import the message and XP value from a [website](https://mee6.xyz/grakami) into my Sheet, I got the following two importxml functions:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://mee6.xyz/grakami"; "/html/body/div[@id='app-mount']/div/div[@class='sc-6rly6x-1 sc-6rly6x-3 sc-1kdz257-0 dNbMwg glJEau hCdQdR']/div[@class='leaderboardBody']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayersListContainer']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayersList']/div/div[1]/div[@class='leaderboardPlayer']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayerStats']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayerStatBlock'][1]/div[@class='leaderboardPlayerStatValue']")

=IMPORTXML("https://mee6.xyz/grakami"; "/html/body/div[@id='app-mount']/div/div[@class='sc-6rly6x-1 sc-6rly6x-3 sc-1kdz257-0 dNbMwg glJEau hCdQdR']/div[@class='leaderboardBody']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayersListContainer']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayersList']/div/div[1]/div[@class='leaderboardPlayer']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayerStats']/div[@class='leaderboardPlayerStatBlock'][2]/div[@class='leaderboardPlayerStatValue']")
```

The only problem I got with both of them: it's returning #NV.

Sorry if this is very easy, but I'm not familiar to xPath's and XML at all.

Answer (score 0):

the "website" you trying to scrape is behind the login which is not supported by any import formulae of google sheets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was automatically logged in so I didn't noticed it.